# Including the day of the week in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database

How would I go about changing the way a 'sign up' date is displayed in a MySQL table? I wanted the date to be formatted in this way: **Monday, August 26 2013 6:04PM** instead of the usual, standard format based on a 24 hour clock.

Currently I have:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First']);
$value2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Last']);
$value3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['City']);
$value4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['State']);
$value5 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Country']);
$value6 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
```

SQL:

```
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO members
    (First, Last, City, State, Country, Email, Date)
  VALUES
    ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6', NOW())
";
```

I thought changing the format was as simple as this:

```
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO members
    (First, Last, City, State, Country, Email, Date) 
  VALUES
    ('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4','$value5','$value6' ("l-F-j-Y))
";
```

Answer (score 2):

Let the date be a date. Just store it the way MySQL wants it to store it and then transform it the way you want it to look like in your presentation layer. Even if there isn't any presentation layer just format the date in a select statement using the date formatting functions in MySQL.

Check [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to see those functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to help you format the date. It will work exactly how you want it.

But, I personally prefer to have the unix timestamp in the database, and then have the above function to format it any way I want; that allows you to change it from format to format at any time, without having to manually edit every database entry.

**NOTE**: You should look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) because the MySQL functions will be removed in future versions of PHP.

Comment: Yes, you should worry about this display in the display layer, but I would strongly disagree with anyone who suggests storing dates as unix timestamps in the database rather than using the native date, datetime, or timestamp data types for the columns.  In all but the most specific use cases, it is better to use the date/time field types.

Comment: Almost inevitably, when you place a date field in your database, someone will want to query against it, whether for use within the application or simply in reporting. When you have a unix timestamp field it is extremely painful to work with for these purposes, as you need to convert the field into a datetime format to do things like "show me all records for the current month".  Because you have to convert the field value, this prevents you from using any kind of index on the field for executing your query.